# Solving a system ODE's with PyDSTool

Tags: python, integration, ode

I am trying to solve a dynamical system with multiple degrees of freedom (DOF) with the PyDSTool package. The ODE's are defined as:

> M ddx + D dx + K x = f,

where `dx` and `ddx` are first and second derivatives of `x`. For the sake of simplicity I first want to solve a 2 DOF system (and later larger systems), with the following matrices:

```
M = [[10,  0],
     [ 0,  8]]

K = [[  4000000.,  -3000000.],
     [ -3000000.,  10000000.]]

D = [[  400.,  -300.],
     [ -300.,  1000.]]

f = [[300 * sin(100*t)],
     [0]]
```

and where the displacement vector is defined as:

```
x = [[x1],
     [x2]]
```

I tried the 1 DOF example from documentation, which can be found [here](https://github.com/robclewley/pydstool/blob/master/examples/forced_spring.py), however I am a bit lost on how to expand it to a larger system. Could someone help me on with the multiple degree of freedom case?

Comment: it seems to me that  you cannot use matrix/vector notation with PyDSTool, but will have to spell out the equations separately as in this example: https://github.com/robclewley/pydstool/blob/master/examples/PyCont_Brusselator.py which has six degrees of freedom `(X1, X2, X3, Y1, Y2, Y3)`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be it. I think I will rewrite the equations with the help of `sympy`. I will post the solution later.